# Could not find input file symfony

Tags: symfony, propel

I am able to generate bundle. But I face problem when building model using propel. I tried `php symfony propel:build-model` to generate model but it throws error - **could not open input file: symfony**. `php app/console cache:clear` works fine for me. Will I have to set environmental variable for symfony too. I am on window 7 32bit machine. I am using symfony2. Any suggestion will be very helpful to me.

Comment: Does the file "symfony" exist ? And if yes, what are the rights ? (777 ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `php app/console propel:build-model` instead of `php symfony propel:build-model`. The `app/console` part is just a reference to the `console` file inside the `app` directory. That file is the main entrance for all console commands in your Symfony application.

The `php` part tells the console to use the `php` command to execute the `app/console` file and `propel:build-model` is the command you execute.

EDIT: From the comments: Also don't forget to add the bundle to `AppKernel::registerBundles`.

Comment: I have also tried <code>php app/console propel:build-model</code> but with no success. Is there any other way to generate model and schema.

Comment: Did you installed the PropelBundle?

Comment: @Gautam and activated it in the `AppKernel`?

Comment: I thought composer automatically keep the the things in AppKernel. I got it now. So thanks for the help.