# Symfony3 commands, could not open input file: symfony

Tags: php, console, symfony

Enviroment: XAMPP server (windows), PHP 5.6.28 (cli), Composer version 1.2.2 2016-11-03 17:43:15
I have problem with Symfony3 commands. I entered project directory and type command below I can see result:

```
# php symfony -v
Could not open input file: symfony
```

Below there are requirements:

```
# php bin\symfony_requirements

Symfony Requirements Checker
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> PHP is using the following php.ini file:
  D:\xampp\php\php.ini

> Checking Symfony requirements:
  .............................WWW......


 [OK]
 Your system is ready to run Symfony projects


Optional recommendations to improve your setup
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

 * intl extension should be available
   > Install and enable the intl extension (used for validators).

 * a PHP accelerator should be installed
   > Install and/or enable a PHP accelerator (highly recommended).

 * realpath_cache_size should be at least 5M in php.ini
   > Setting "realpath_cache_size" to e.g. "5242880" or "5M" in
   > php.ini* may improve performance on Windows significantly in some
   > cases.


Note  The command console could use a different php.ini file
~~~~  than the one used with your web server. To be on the
      safe side, please check the requirements from your web
      server using the web/config.php script.
```

Project was generated by command:

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name
```

I couldn't use `php symfony new project_name` due to problem above.
Also solution from this topis doesn't work for me:

[Could not find input file symfony](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855008/could-not-find-input-file-symfony)

Result of using app/console:

> Could not open input file: app/console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'console' file was moved to 'bin' directory in Symfony3
http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/usage.html

Anyway, an up-to-date way of using Symfony Installer is described here https://github.com/symfony/symfony-installer

Comment: Thank you! I tried bin/console before but it should be bin\console under Windows ;-) It mean I made wrong backslash type.
Full proper command under Windows is:
`php bin\console`
Thanks for links.

Comment: Finally ! Thank you this is what I was looking for